# Apache Tomcat 8 always promts for password

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have set up roles and username for tomcat manger and when I run it I am always promted for credentials and after I input them I am promted again. What is the problem?

Here is my tomcat-users.xml:

```
   <role rolemane="manager-gui"/>
   <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
   <user username="admin" password="admin" roles"manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
```

Comment: Can you provide the Catalina output or the output of some log file likely `manager.2014-03-xx.log` in Tomcat logs directory? Alternatively you can start tomcat and have it output in the console using the daemon.sh script in Tomcat's bin directory with the argument run : `tomcat_root/bin/daemon.sh run` on Linux. On windows all this is probably a bit different but the idea remains.

Comment: 3/18/14 2:11:23.967 PM WDQuickView[2279]: Updating service information
Here is what I see in log when I'm trying to login

Comment: Please post the entire contents of your tomcat-users file not just an extract.